# Help with bitcoin gold explorer: using explorer after fork

Tags: bitcoin-gold

I tried to view my free BTG using the bitcoin address, but it doesn't recognize the address. The explorer was at: btgexplorer.com.  Yet, when I try the same thing at bitcoingold.org, there they have a utility titled "CHECK YOUR ADDRESS BALANCE BEFORE BLOCK 491407", it works fine. What is the problem with the explorer? I also get the same error with the explorer at btgexp.com.

Comment: Voting to close as this needs to be raised with the individuals providing the service. It does sound like a bug.

Comment: It happens on two different explorers, so I wonder if there's some kind of manipulation that is needed to convert my Bitcoin address to a Bitcoin Gold address. The Bitcoin address was 15R8nVATQzSpp7tHMdAwQBcPimNTYXNz2J

Comment: It may also be that they used the same buggy code. I see that btgexplorer.com doesn't even recognise the address as a valid address; it gives error "Unrecognized search pattern".

Comment: Have you used a bitcoin gold explorer that works?  Where can I find it? By the way, the address I posted above has .0006 bitcoin and so it should have .0006 bitcoin gold, since this account was established on 8/27/17, way before the fork. Thanks.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any way to get help from the developers of this explorer. And I did not have the same problem when Bitcoin Cash was created; every explorer I tried worked fine for Bitcoin Cash.

Comment: I can just confirm the same issue: I have not found a BTG explorer that works on any of my addresses (that all had BTC at the time of the split)

Comment: btgexp.com sometimes doesn't even find addresses it presents itself (i.e. look up an old transaction, then click one of the addresses, you sometimes get the same "not found" error). Oliver's bitinfocharts link works well.

Comment: How can this question be classified when it is asking for a working BTG explorer? Something very basic and needed for anyone handling BTG but still currently hard to find

Comment: *meant "How can this question be put on hold as off topic"

Answer (score 4):

After more googling I found this one: https://bitinfocharts.com/bitcoin%20gold/
It displays the correct BTG balances for my addresses at least

Comment: thank you, thank you, thank you. I wish some developer would explain why this is  occurring.  But this was a BIG relief.

Comment: note that when you enter a valid BTC address it shows you a BTG balance with the corresponding BTG address, so there is definately some BTC->BTG addresses translation logic going on.

Comment: I just noticed the same thing. It reports the correct balance but it does not report the address correctly.