# BTG address not found but there was a BTC transaction before 24-10-2017 on it, how to check BTG balance?

Tags: balance, bitcoin-gold

I have an old paper wallet that was printed with https://bitcoinpaperwallet.com/. It has 0,1 BTC incoming on 2017-06-21 and 0,1 BTC outgoing on 2017-12-11.

So the BTC balance is zero, but since the fork of BTC to BTG (Bitcoin Gold) was on 2017-10-24 there should be a balance of 0,1 BTG on that address on the BTG network.

First I wanted to verify my theory that the BTG balance is actually there. But all of these sites say that address doesn't exist or is wrong.

- https://explorer.bitcoingold.org/insight/
- https://btg.tokenview.com/
- https://btgexplorer.com/

What am I missing here? Why is the address missing on these BTG explorers or how can I actually check my BTG balance?

Comment: I just found the balance by using another explorer thanks to this answer https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/62631/help-with-bitcoin-gold-explorer-using-explorer-after-fork

When I understand more about why BTG explorer A is not able to find the address, but BTG explorer B is, I will make this into a proper answer

Comment: BTG changed its address format when it forked off to make the addresses incompatible between BTG and BTC. You can convert BTC addresses to BTG addresses using e.g. https://blog.ledger.com/btg-convert/.